# Problemas setInterval en IE

Tags: angular, typescript, setinterval

he realizado una pantalla en la cual se me muestra una tabla con su consulta a BBDD. He hecho las pruebas en chrome y funciona perfectamente, pero al probar en IE 11, la tabla sólo me muestra el primer registro y tengo que ir clickando sobre el registro para hacer que vayan saliendo los siguientes.

**COMPONENTE**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTiempoRecarga();
    this.cargarTabla();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  private cargarDatos() {
    this.getDatosTabla("0").subscribe((solicitudes : any[]) => {
      this.solicitudes = solicitudes;
    });
  }

  private getDatosTabla(estado: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.gestorService.getDatosTabla(estado).pipe(
      map((response: any[]) => {
        return response;
      })
    );
  }

  private getTiempoRecarga() {
    this.gestorService.getTiempoRecarga().subscribe((propiedades) => {
      this.interval = propiedades;
      this.updateSolicitudes();
    });
  }

  private updateSolicitudes() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
      this.cargarSolicitudesPendientes();
    }, this.interval);
  }
```

He comprobado en [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=setinterval) y soporta el setInverval ¿Alguien sabe porqué puede fallar sólo en IE?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. La versión es la IE11. ya he modificado la pregunta añadiendo la versión. En base a tu respuesta, sólo habría que cambiar el método updateSolicitudes()?

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Esto no es Javascript sino Typescript. Angular se transpila a Javascript, con lo que puedes elegir el nivel de compatibilidad, permitiendo el uso de IE11 (IE10 y anteriores seguramente no).

Comment: Por otro lado, el método `cargarSolicitudesPendientes` no está en el código mostrado, es posible que el error esté ahí. Además, el uso de `this.interval` no me queda nada claro. ¿Cuál es su valor inicial? ¿Lo reusas para guardar el ID del intervalo?

Comment: @PabloLozano El valor inicial esta dentro de `updateSolicitudes`. La asignacion es `this.interval = setInterval( ....` Lo utiliza para detener el intervalo mas adelante con `clearInterval(this.interval)` en `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por la corrección. Borro mis comentarios entonces para no liar a otras personas.

Comment: @Angel veo que `this.interval` no es la causa, pero entonces el error debe estar en el método `cargarSolicitudesPendientes`

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando la variable `this.interval` con dos tipos de datos diferentes o hasta tres diferentes.

```js
 private getTiempoRecarga() {
    this.gestorService.getTiempoRecarga().subscribe((propiedades) => {
      //1.- Aqui le estas cargando propiedades
      this.interval = propiedades;
      this.updateSolicitudes();
    });
  }

  private updateSolicitudes() {
    //2.-Aqui le estas asignando un intervalo
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
      this.cargarSolicitudesPendientes();
    //3.-Aqui deberia ir un numero en milisegundos. 
    }, this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: Aunque el uso es un poco extraño, parece que el reusar la propiedad no es el origen del problema

Comment: @PabloLozano Podría ser a la hora de transpilar a javascript?